# facebook app working with https link only

Tags: facebook, https

First of all i would like to apologize if there is a thread with the same problem, but I couldn't find it.

I'm developing a facebook app, what is not published yet.

We enabled SSL on it, but from that time, if we don't write https into the url (https://apps.facebook.com/myapp) the content is not scrollable, it cuts the page at the half.

Could you tell me how can i set https as default, so when users click on it on facebook, it would automaticly loads in https.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Szia, már elfogyott a bejgli? Kellemes karácsonyt! :)

Comment: @biziclop hungarian is not official language on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make both Canvas URL and Secure Canvas URL same in your app settings, use HTTPS for both.

Comment: If it answers your question then please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark at the left of the answer above. Thanks.

Comment: It didnt help me, i just tested it sorry.

Comment: The problem is when i click on the app in facebook, its still not https. And javascript does because of unsafe errors.